# What variation of SQL is used for Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I just started using Amazon Athena and I can make simple SELECT statements, but it's clearly not T-SQL. What database is Athena based on, at least for the SQL query portion?

Comment: Amazon Athena is based on [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/).

Comment: Post that as an answer, please.

Comment: "it's clearly not T-SQL" …why would it be T-SQL? Have you read any documentation about the product?

Comment: I said it wasn't T-SQL because certain features of T-SQL didn't work. So, I was asking what type of SQL it was based on.

Answer (score 1):

Athena supports ANSI SQL, as does almost every other SQL database.

T-SQL is Microsoft’s extension to ANSI SQL that provides some programming capabilities - similar to PL/SQL in Oracle.

As T-SQL is proprietary to MS, it’s not surprising that an AWS product doesn’t support it.